# Como crear una expresión regular que acepte caracteres especiales?

Tags: regex, pcre

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular:

```
^(?=(?:.*\d){1})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){1})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){1})\S{8,16}$
```

Intente completar este ejemplo pero necesito agregar a esta regex que valide caracteres especiales, ejemplo: `(@$?¡-_)`.

La expresión regular debe validar lo siguiente:

> longitud 8-16 caracteres
>   validar al menos 1 dígito
>   validar al menos 1 letra mayúscula
>   validar letras minúsculas y
>   Validar al menos 1 carácter especial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede agregar el grupo de los caracteres especiales en la siguiente forma:

```
^(?=(?:.*\d){1})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){1})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){1})(?=(?:.*[@$?¡\-_]){1})\S{8,16}$
```

lo único que hay que escapar en este caso dentro de los [] es el "-", porque normalmente significa un rango de caracteres.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado

Comment: Si te ha funcionado, por favor acepta la respuesta para que oros usuarios que buscan este problema o uno parecido pueden ver que hay una respuesta que resultó. Así funciona SO.

Comment: @StefanNolde Noto que utilizas `?` al inicio, esto ¿Qué indica? tambien veo que utilizas `=` y `:`